# Should I add multiple secondary index to search

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a search screen on my app where the users can use up to 4 parameters to search. I have written a stored procedure to facilitate the search.

```
Select 
    ID,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    CountryCd,
    State,
    Zip,
    Data1,
    Data2,
    Data3
From 
    Customer
Where 
    ((FirstName like @paramfname) OR (@paramfname IS NULL) )
    AND ((LastName like @paramlname) OR (@paramlname IS NULL))
    AND CountryCd = @paramcountry
    AND ((Zip = @paramzip) OR  (@paramzip IS NULL))
```

I have added one secondary index that includes all 4 columns `FirstName,LastName,CountryCd` and `Zip`.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_Cust_FN_Ctry] 
ON [dbo].[Customer]([FirstName] ASC, [LastName] ASC, [CountryCd] ASC, [Zip] ASC)
```

My question: is this one index enough for efficient search? If the user runs a search, by using only `FirstName` and `Country`, does SQL Server know how to use the index efficiently?

Or do i need to add 4 seperate Secondary Index on each of these fields ?

Thanks

Comment: SQL Server *might* use your index *IF* you're using the n left-most columns - e.g. if you query on just `FirstName`, or on `FirstName` and `LastName`, or on `FirstName`, `LastName` and `CountryCd` - but it will **NOT** be able to use the index if you query on `FirstName` and `CountryCD` (since those are **not** the n left-most columns in the index)

Comment: May be that is why, i have 3 millions rows and the query is slow, taking 4 to 5 seconds. Just curious to see what others are doing in this situation.

Comment: Also, because you're asking for more columns than the index can provide, SQL Server will always have to either do a number of key lookups (which are slow) or use a table scan (which also is slow). If you would query only on those columns included in the index (plus `ID`), I'm sure your query would be much faster

Comment: SQL Server will *never* use indexes for conditions like `((col=@var) OR (@var IS NULL))`.  This is what will make your performance problems.

Comment: This question requires basic understanding of indexes, which you do not have. Do some research on your own first. This will help you much more than get a one-off answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this query, I would lead the index with `CountryCd` as that is the only column that is guaranteed to be searched. This of course assumes that the selectivity of `CountryCd` is selective for your data.

If you want to get really fancy, you can add a computed column that contains the SOUNDEX of `FirstName` and another for `LastName` and index those. If you do, you can express the filter like this

```
((FirstNameSound = SOUNDEX(@paramfname)) OR (@paramfname IS NULL) )
AND ((LastNameSound = SOUNDEX(@paramlname) OR (@paramlname IS NULL))
AND CountryCd = @paramcountry
AND ((Zip = @paramzip) OR  (@paramzip IS NULL))
```

This only works for English sounding names - you should understand the meaning of the SOUNDEX function before doing this.

Regarding your question about 1-4 indexes: This really depends on what is normally searched together. If any combination is equally likely, you probably need all four indexes (or at the very least, index on the columns that are selective). If `FirstName` plus `LastName` is typically searched together, you should have an index on those two columns.

However, let me challenge your design a bit. It really looks like you are trying to solve a fulltext index problem with traditional indexes. I would recommend having a look at the fulltext indexing engine in SQL Server before finalising the design.

Answer (score 0):

if user would search by first name and country than index would most probably be beneficial. However if a user would use only last name by a search than the index would have to be read entirely - index scan.

Note that index key column order does matter because it tells SQL Server how to logically sort the index. While designing an index and its key columns

([FirstName] ASC, [LastName] ASC, [CountryCd] ASC, [Zip] ASC)

you should start with the most selective one. In this case I believe would be the last name. I wrote a blog post on this subject: http://sqlmate.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/interview-question-2/

In some cases adding multiple indexes to support reads is necessary. But be careful to not overindex :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use dynamic sql and eliminate the search criteria for any parameter that was null and eliminate all of the slow or clauses..they will likely cause the optimize to skip a useful index.